# Find a subsequence $\{\eta_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and $\eta$ with finite moment s.t. $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E[|\eta_{n_k} - \eta|]=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1 ,X_2, X_3, ...$ be a sequence of iid Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda > 0$, and let $\eta_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}X_k$. Is it possible to find a subsequence $\{\eta_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and a non-zero random variable $\eta$ with finite moment s.t. $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E[|\eta_{n_k} - \eta|]=0$?

So far, I can show the sequence $\{\eta_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to zero in probability, but how to use this to show the above question? Thanks.

Comment: I imagine that it depends upon $\lambda$?

Comment: I think so, but how?

Comment: I am not following: you know the value of each $\mathbb E[\eta_{n_k}]$ hence you know the value of $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E[\eta_{n_k}]$ hence you know the value of $\mathbb E[\eta]$ if $\eta$ exists. Thus you can already conclude for every value of $\lambda$ except one. Can you do that?

Comment: ((The OP now mentions $\mathbb E[|\eta_{n_k} - \eta|]$ instead of $\mathbb E[\eta_{n_k} - \eta]$. Signaling the modification to commenters was not an option, it seems.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the $X_k$'s being independent. Then
$$ E \eta_n = \prod_{1\leq k \leq n} E X_k = \lambda^n .$$
So we need $\lambda\leq 1$.

As I see no absolute signs in the condition $\lim E (\eta_{n_k}- \eta)=1$:
For $\lambda=1$ take $\eta=1$ (const).
For $\lambda<1$ take $\eta$ any non-zero random variable with average 
zero (and finite moments).

The sequence $\eta_n$ converges to zero a.s.: To see this note that on the set $\Omega_N=\{ \prod_{1\leq k\leq N} X_k=0 \}$ the sequence $\eta_n$ vanishes for $n>N$, whence converges to zero on that set. And $\cup_N \Omega_N$ has probability 1.

Later edit (new version with absolute signs):
If we wish to ensure $E|\eta_{n_k}-\eta| \rightarrow 0$ then this is impossible not only for $\lambda>1$ (clear) but also for $\lambda=1$: This is because $\eta_n$ converges to zero a.s. and implies $\lim_n E|\eta_{n}-\eta|= 1 + E|\eta| \geq 1$. For $\lambda<1$ we must have $\eta=0$ (a.s.) wbut this  was excluded by hypothesis. So the answer is no, there is no value of $\lambda$ for which such $\eta$ exists.

Comment: Rugh, Sorry, the problem should have absolute sign, but does it matter?